# How to implement a custom simple `Future`?

Tags: scala, future

I'm trying to implement a simple custom `Future`, which is similar to `scala.concurrent.Future`, but much simpler.

I defined a trait like:

```
trait MyFuture[+T] {
  def map[K](f: T => K): MyFuture[K]
  def flatMap[K](f: T => MyFuture[K]): MyFuture[K]
  def recover[K](f: Throwable => K): MyFuture[K]
  def recoverWith[K](f: Throwable => MyFuture[K]): MyFuture[K]
}

object MyFuture {
  def apply[T](body: => T): MyFuture[T] = ???
}

object MyAwait {
  def result[T](myFuture: MyFuture[T], atMost: Int /*mills*/): T = ???
}
```

And I can do such things based on these APIs:

```
val future = MyFuture(3).map(_+1).flatMap(x=>MyFuture(x*x))
val result = MyAwait.result(future,100)
// result: 16
```

Unfortunatly, I can't find a way to implement it. I've looked into `scala.concurrent.Future`, but which is too complex for learning

Comment: I would start from submitting [callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) into some implicitly added thread-pool inside `apply`. This task should run `body` and then call subscribers. `map`, `flatMap` etc should add subscribers and call them if they're not called and your callable is done. And, btw, it all should be thread safe, so you need concurrent collections and CAS for list of subscribers. That's how actual scala's `Future` works...more-less as it actually uses concept of promise (subscribable event) for `map`/`flatMap` implementation.

Comment: [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/concurrent/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent/Future.scala) has a quite bare-bone implementation with an underlying ADT, using, I think, not a thread pool, but continuations.

Comment: @phg implementation you're talking about is based on "Free" monad and thread-pools as well (for its execution). `Async` word here might be confusing, but really is just case class implementing a `Future`.

Comment: @phg `Async` takes a handler which takes `A => Trampoline[A]`, that in its turn is actually next handler in a chain. Default implementation executes computation in another thread (using callable - see my first comment), obtains a trampoline (Free monad) using result and calls it to move on.

Comment: Why not simply have a `def peer: scala.concurrent.Future[A]`?

Comment: @dk14 Ah, ok, thanks for pointing that out -- seems like it has more layers than I thought... For anybody else: the actual references to thread pools are only at [the end](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/concurrent/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent/Future.scala#L377) of the code (and thus easily overlooked).